# How get list of registerd post types in specific site in multisite network?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, multisite

I have the multisite network and a few plugins with registered post types. Some sites don`t use some plugins and don`t have post types which plugin provides. How I can retrieve registered post types for each site?

`get_post_types()` returns me all registered post types, which presents in my network. But I wanna `switch_to_blog(3)` and get post types actual for this one site.

If this is unreal, then how I can exclude unused post types from the list?